# Cannot Flatten NumPy ndarray/ How to read binary file more intelligently

Tags: arrays, numpy, mesh

I am writing a numpy based .PLY importer.  I am only interested in binary files, and vertices, faces and vertex colors.  My target data format is a flattened list of x,y,z floats for the vertex data and r,g,b,a integers for the color data.

```
 [x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1....xn,yn,zn] 
 [r0,g0,b0,a0,r1,g1,b1,a1....rn,gn,bn,an]
```

This allows me to use fasts builtin C++ methods to construct the mesh in the target program (Blender).

I am using a modified version of this code to read in the data into numpy arrays [example](https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/blob/master/pyntcloud/io/ply.py)

```
valid_formats = {'binary_big_endian': '>','binary_little_endian': '<'}
ply = open(filename, 'rb')
# get binary_little/big or ascii
fmt = ply.readline().split()[1].decode()
# get extension for building the numpy dtypes
ext = valid_formats[fmt]
ply.seek(end_header)
#v_dtype = [('x','<f4'),('y','<f4'), ('z','<f4'), ('red','<u1'), ('green','<u1'), ('blue','<u1'),('alpha','<u1')]
#points_size = (previously read in from header)
points_np = np.fromfile(ply, dtype=v_dtype, count=points_size)
```

The results being

```
print(points_np.shape)
print(points_np[0:3])
print(points_np.ravel()[0:3])

>>>(158561,)
>>>[ (20.781816482543945, 11.767952919006348, 15.565438270568848, 206, 216, 186, 255)
     (20.679922103881836, 11.754084587097168, 15.560364723205566, 189, 196, 157, 255)
     (20.72969627380371, 11.823691368103027, 15.51106071472168, 192, 193, 157, 255)]
>>>[ (20.781816482543945, 11.767952919006348, 15.565438270568848, 206, 216, 186, 255)
     (20.679922103881836, 11.754084587097168, 15.560364723205566, 189, 196, 157, 255)
     (20.72969627380371, 11.823691368103027, 15.51106071472168, 192, 193, 157, 255)]
```

So the ravel (I've also tried flatten, reshape etc) does work and I presume it is because the data types are (float, float, float, int, int, int).

**What I have tried**
-I've tried doing things like vectorizing a function that just pulls out the xyz and rgb separately into a new array.
-I've tried stack, vstack etc
List comprehension (yuck)
-Things like thes take **1 to 10s of seconds** to execute compared to **hundredths of seconds** to read in the data. 
-I have tried using astype on the verts data, but that seems to return only the first element.

[convert to structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176949/convert-list-of-tuples-to-structured-numpy-array%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245187/accessing-the-first-items-in-a-numpy-array-of-tuples%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)
[accessing first element of each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245187/accessing-the-first-items-in-a-numpy-array-of-tuples)
[Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

**What I want to Try/Would Like to Know**

Is there a better way to read the data in the data in the first place so I don't loose all this time reshaping, flattening etc? Perhaps by telling np.fromfile to skip over the color data on one pass and then come back and read it again?

Is there a numpy trick I don't know for reshaping/flattening data of this kind

Comment: With a shape of (158561,) your array is already "flat", that is, 1d.  So it's a waste of your time to try to change that with ravel, reshape, etc.  You haven't taken seriously the meaning of array `shape`.

Comment: Given the file structure, using `fromfile` with that compound `dtype` is the only way.  Now you have a 1d structured array.  The next question is - what do you need to do with that.  The `dtype` defines fields, which you can access individually or in subsets, `points_np['x']` or `points_np[['x','y']]`.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: "which you can access individually or in subsets"  Thank you, this was the hole in my understanding of the data I was getting back from "fromfile"